# Reliance on 3rd party packages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to better understand the "risks" of building with 3rd party packages and `npm` more broadly

If I `npm install` some 3rd party package like `semantic-ui-react`, is there any chance that in the future I won't be able to use the package on my site? Or will I always be able to use the package for that specific version that was installed? I'm assuming I do not perform any upgrades etc. I presume these packages are "decentralized" and "censorship" resistant?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Registry data is immutable, meaning once published, a package cannot change. We do this for reasons of security and stability of the users who depend on those packages. So if you've ever published a package called "bob" at version 1.1.0, no other package can ever be published with that name at that version. This is true even if that package is unpublished.

I recommend reading the npm unpublish policy docs:

https://docs.npmjs.com/policies/unpublish